# Flask and long running tasks

Tags: python, caching, flask

I'm writing a small web server using Flask that needs to do the following things:

1. On the first request, serve the basic page and kick off a long (15-60 second) data processing task. The data processing task queries a second server which I do not control, updates a local database, and then performs some calculations on the results to show in the web page.
2. The page issues several AJAX requests that all depend on parts of the result from the long task, so I need to wait until the processing is done.
3. Subsequent requests for the first page would ideally re-use the previous request's result if they come in while the processing task is ongoing (or even shortly thereafter)

I tried using flask-cache (specifically SimpleCache), but ran into an issue as it seems the cache pickles the result, when I'd really rather keep the exact object.

I suppose I could re-write what I'm caching to be pickle-able, and then implement a single worker thread to do the processing.

Is there some more better way of handling this kind of workflow?

Answer (score 2):

I think best way for long data processing is something like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

1. Send request to run task and receive task ID.
2. Periodically send ajax requests to check task progress and receive result of task execution.